# Why doesn’t this renaming columns code reflect?

Tags: python, function, rename

```
def rename(dataframe,deflt_col_name,col_rename):
    return dataframe.rename({deflt_col_name:col_rename}, inplace = True)
rename(df,"MSSubClass","mssubclass")
```

Please, explain me why does not it change the column name in data frame.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: by default rename is used to rename index, you need to use the keyword `columns=` or `axis=1`

Comment: @Reza  Its working, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default rename is used to rename an index, you need to use the keyword columns= or axis=1. Try this

```
dataframe.rename(columns={deflt_col_name:col_rename}, inplace = True)
```

or

```
dataframe.rename({deflt_col_name:col_rename}, axis=1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df = rename(df,"MSSubClass","mssubclass")
```

You need to assign the returned DataFrame back to original dataframe. In your case , it is `df`.